# Is it possible to make single VSBuild/VSTest pipeline tasks for multiple build platforms?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, vstest.console.exe

**Edit (TL;DR-Answer):** No, it is not possible to make a single task for either VSBuild or VSTest that encompasses more than one build platform (or build configuration, for that matter). It is possible to configure both of them only once per YAML as described in the accepted answer by @bright-ran-msft below; however, it is still necessary to produce a separate task for each platform.

---

I am currently trying to create an Azure DevOps CI pipeline that builds different .NET and C++ projects for different build platforms (`x64`, `x86`, `Any CPU`) and tests them using MSTest and the CppUnitTestFramework.

The YAML-Pipeline currently contains the following tasks for building and testing the projects:

```yaml
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: Build x86 - Release
  inputs:
    solution: 'Solution.sln'
    platform: 'x86'
    configuration: 'Release'
    maximumCpuCount: true
    msbuildArchitecture: 'x64'
    logFileVerbosity: minimal

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: Test Any CPU - Release
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*Test.dll
    searchFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Bin\AnyCPU\Release'
    runInParallel: true
    runTestsInIsolation: true

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: Test x86 - Release
    inputs:
      testAssemblyVer2: |
        **\*Test.dll
      searchFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Bin\Win32\Release'
      runInParallel: true
      runTestsInIsolation: true

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: Build x64 - Release
  inputs:
    solution: 'Solution.sln'
    platform: 'x64'
    configuration: 'Release'
    maximumCpuCount: true
    msbuildArchitecture: 'x64'
    logFileVerbosity: minimal

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: Test x64 - Release
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*Test.dll
    searchFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Bin\x64\Release'
    runInParallel: true
    runTestsInIsolation: true
```

I am trying to minimize the amount of tasks. In my mind, it should be possible to achieve the same outcome as in the YAML above in a simpler manner. I would *expect* something like the following (note that I changed the path in the `searchFolder` in order to fetch all subdirectories of the build platforms):

```yaml
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: Build - Release
  inputs:
    solution: 'Solution.sln'
    configuration: 'Release'
    maximumCpuCount: true
    msbuildArchitecture: 'x64'
    logFileVerbosity: minimal

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: Test - Release
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*Test.dll
    searchFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Bin'
    runInParallel: true
    runTestsInIsolation: true
```

I have tried to keep both of the build tasks and merge all three test tasks into one. Some of the tests succeeded while the majority failed. This is significant since executing those tests in separated tasks made all of them succeed.

In conclusion:

- Is it possible to write a build task that encapsulates all build platforms (`x64`, `x86`, `Any CPU`)?
- Is it possible to write a test task that tests all DLL-Files regardless of their build platform?
- If one or both of them are not realizable, why would that be the case and does that mean that the original YAML from above is actually the most concise method of formulating these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like as below:

```yaml
. . .

parameters:
- name: buildPlatforms
  type: object
  default:
  - 'Any CPU'
  - 'x64'
  - 'x86'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  TestProjectName: {Your Test Project Name}

jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: 'Build'
  steps:
  . . .
  
  - ${{ each buildPlatform in parameters.buildPlatforms }}:
    - task: VSBuild@1
      displayName: 'Build ${{ buildPlatform }} - $(buildConfiguration)'
      inputs:
        solution: 'Solution.sln'
        ${{ if eq(buildPlatform, 'Any CPU') }}:
          msbuildArgs: '-p:OutputPath=bin\AnyCPU\$(buildConfiguration)'
        ${{ else }}:
          msbuildArgs: '-p:OutputPath=bin\${{ buildPlatform }}\$(buildConfiguration)'
        platform: ${{ buildPlatform }}
        configuration: $(buildConfiguration)
        maximumCpuCount: true
        logFileVerbosity: minimal
    
    - task: VSTest@3
      displayName: 'Test ${{ buildPlatform }} - $(buildConfiguration)'
      inputs:
        testAssemblyVer2: |
          **\*test*.dll
          !**\*TestAdapter.dll
          !**\obj\**
        ${{ if eq(buildPlatform, 'Any CPU') }}:
          searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(TestProjectName)\bin\AnyCPU\$(buildConfiguration)'
          testRunTitle: 'Test-AnyCPU-$(buildConfiguration)'
        ${{ else }}:
          searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(TestProjectName)\bin\${{ buildPlatform }}\$(buildConfiguration)'
          testRunTitle: 'Test-${{ buildPlatform }}-$(buildConfiguration)'
        runInParallel: true
        runTestsInIsolation: true
```

By this, the pipeline will generate a build step and a test step for each platform (**`Any CPU`**, **`x64`** and **`x86`**) within the same job.

[image]

Related documentations:

- [**Runtime parameters**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script)
- [**Template parameters**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/template-parameters?view=azure-devops#parameter-data-types)
- [**Expressions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion)

---

Comment: Thank you, this would certainly make the YAML file shorter! However, the configuration still produces six tasks; two for each build platform. Is it possible to write only two tasks to accomplish all of this (i.e. one that builds all three build platforms and one that tests all of them)?

Comment: @Huadara, No. Each VSbuild task and VSTest task can run with only one `buildPlatform` and one `buildConfiguration` each time. It is not possible to use only one VSbuild task and one VSTest task to run with all the configurations at once. With the way I shared above, you just need to configure one VSbuild task and one VSTest task in your pipeline. When running the pipeline, it will automatically copy a VSbuild task and a VSTest task with each configuration.